# Typescript can't find external module when referenced by two different files

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

I may be missing something obvious, but Typescript's module resolver for commonjs isn't working as expected.

Given the following directory structure and files:

```
./first/shared.ts
./first/second/class_a.ts
./first/second/class_b.ts
./third/class_c.ts
```

Where:

- class_a references shared.ts
- class_b references class_a.ts and class_c.ts
- class_c references shared.ts

Specifically:

```
shared.ts:
class Shared{}
export = Shared;

class_a.ts:
import Shared = require('../shared');
class A{}
export = A;

class_b.ts:
import A = require('./class_a');
import C = require('../../third/class_c');
class B {}
export = B;

class_c.ts:
import Shared = require('../first/shared');
class C {}
export = C;
```

All compile except class_b.ts, using the following compiler invocation:

```
tsc --module commonjs class_a.ts
```

Compiling class_b.ts fails with the error that it can't find shared.ts:

```
../../third/class_c.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find external module '../first/shared'.
```

Note that if you reverse the order of imports in class_b.ts, you get a different error:

```
class_a.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find external module '../shared'.
```

It seems the compiler is finding shared.ts the first time it is imported, but not the second time.

I'm using tsc 1.4.1.0.

Anything obvious I'm missing, here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can verify that this is *indeed* a bug:

```
C:\Users\basaratsyed\Downloads\ts\fancyimport\first\second>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.js" --module commonjs class_b.ts
../../third/class_c.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find external module '../first/shared'.
```

That said it does not show up in *the language service API* e.g. *atom-typescript* which is probably why it hasn't been reported yet:

[image]

Note : I've reported it here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2193

Comment: Thanks for checking that and filing a report -- I reported the issue, too :) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2192

Comment: I marked mine as duplicate and closed it. Thanks :)